# Calling a synchronized from inside a non-synchronized method

Tags: java, thread-safety, synchronized

I'm experimenting with Threads and it's not working as expected, despite the fact I've applied Synchronization.

I have a method

```
private synchronized void printStatus(){
        System.out.println("\t\t\t" + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        System.out.println("\t\t\tCookies: " + contents);
}
```

and so I'm expecting, that when ever called, in the output I will get one line after another. But that is not what happens. My output looks like this:

```
            homerThread
            Cookies: 0
            margeThread
0 cookies were Removed
            Cookies: 0
            homerThread
3 cookies were Put
            Cookies: 3
0 cookies were Removed
            margeThread
            Cookies: 3
3 cookies were Put
            homerThread
            Cookies: 6
4 cookies were Removed
            margeThread
            Cookies: 2
1 cookies were Put
            homerThread
            Cookies: 3
3 cookies were Removed
                margeThread
                Cookies: 0
....
```

As you can see, there are a lot of lines that are not synchronized properly

Why is this happening?

---

I've included my entire code below for completeness;

**Main.java class**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) { 

        CookieJar jar = new CookieJar(); 

        Homer homer = new Homer(jar); 
        Marge marge = new Marge(jar); 

        Thread homerThread = new Thread(homer);
        homerThread.setName("homerThread");
        Thread margeThread = new Thread(marge);
        margeThread.setName("margeThread");

        homerThread.start();
        margeThread.start();
    } 

}
```

**Homer.java**

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Homer implements Runnable {

    CookieJar jar; 

    public Homer(CookieJar jar) { 
        this.jar = jar; 
    } 
    public void eat(int amnt) { 
        jar.getCookie(amnt); 
    } 
    public void run() { 
        Random random = new Random();
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            eat(random.nextInt(5));
        } 
    } 
}
```

**Marge**

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Marge implements Runnable {
    CookieJar jar; 
    public Marge(CookieJar jar) { 
        this.jar = jar; 
    } 
    public void bake(int cookie) { 
        jar.putCookie(cookie); 
    } 
    public void run() { 
        Random random = new Random();
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            bake(random.nextInt(5));
        }
    } 


}
```

**CookieJar.java**

```
public class CookieJar {
    int contents = 0; 
    boolean hasCookie = false; 

    public void putCookie(int amount) {  
        printStatus();
        contents += amount;
        System.out.println(amount + " cookies were Put");
    } 

    public void getCookie(int amount) { 
        printStatus();
        contents -= amount;
        System.out.println(amount + " cookies were Removed");
    }

    private synchronized void printStatus(){
        System.out.println("\t\t\t" + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        System.out.println("\t\t\tCookies: " + contents);
    }
}
```

*Note: Yes I realize that Homer might end up eating negative amount of cookies, which may or may not be possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, here's what `synchronized` does:  It prevents two or more threads from synchronizing on the same object at the same time.  It does not do *anything* else.  It does not prevent two threads from entering the same synchronized method at the same time (the threads could be calling the same method on different instances).  Synchronizing on an object does not prevent other threads from modifying that object.  (The other threads might be in un-synchronized methods).

If you want to prevent other threads from printing messages between the two lines that printStatus() prints, then it is not enough to only synchronize printStatus().  You must synchronize *every* thread that can use `System.out`.  Here's how I would do it:

```
private void printStatus() {
    synchronized (System.out) {
        System.out.println("\t\t\t" + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        System.out.println("\t\t\tCookies: " + contents);
    }
}

public void putCookie(int amount) {  
    printStatus();
    contents += amount;
    synchronized (System.out) {
        System.out.println(amount + " cookies were Put");
    }
}

...
```

I am synchronizing on System.out here to illustrate a point.  System.out is the thing that I want to protect  It does not matter what other threads and what other synchronization objects I have in my program, if every method that tries to write to System.out does so from inside `synchronized (System.out)`, then the outputs will all be correctly interleaved.

---

Extra Credit:

In production code, I would have done this instead:

```
private static Object consoleLock = new Object();

...
    synchronized (consoleLock) {
        System.out.println(...);
        ...
    }
...
```

It will have the same effect as synchronizing on System.out as long as I consistently use `consoleLock` everywhere, but it has the advantage that the lock variable is `private`.  That way, I know that no other programmer is going to be synchronizing on my lock for some other reason.  (They'd have to be pretty crazy to synchronize on System.out for any other reason, but then there *are* some crazy developers out there.)

Also note:  I made consoleLock static because System.out is static.  There is only one System.out, so it's important that I have only one lock object.

Comment: So `consoleLock` does nothing other than serve as the parameter to all `synchronize` statements? cool

Comment: Yes.  It's an expression of Robert Martin's Single Responsibility Principle::  Every class, and every object should be responsible for just one thing.  As with any rule, there are situations where it  helps, and there are situations where it only gets in the way.  I try to follow it unless there's a good reason _not_ to.  It makes code easier to maintain because, if the code you have to change only does one thing, then you know you won't be breaking any other code that depends on it to do some other thing.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that these lines:

```
System.out.println(amount + " cookies were Put");

System.out.println(amount + " cookies were Removed");
```

Are not synchronized on `jar`.  If you look at only the `xThread` and `Cookies: N` output, which *are* synchronized, those are always properly ordered.

Comment: "...those are always properly ordered."  But look at the first five lines of output

Comment: @Imray, The lines that are output by printStatus() in your example are all correctly ordered.  If you ignore the lines output by other methods, you see threadName/Cookies/threadName/Cookies/...  What Mark Peters and Erwin Bolwidt are trying to tell you is that you have done nothing to prevent _other_ methods from interleaving their output with the output from printStatus().

Comment: The most important point is that putCookie and getCookie must be synchronized, as mentioned by @Erwin_Bolwidt. Marking printStatus synchronized is then redundant. You can't have two hands in the cookie jar at the same time ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You should also `synchronize` your `getCookie` and `putCookie` methods, otherwise they will interleave with the `printStatus` method.